# Database Table Relations Issue

Tags: mysql, join

Situation:
I got news. NEws are posted in multiple categories.

Issue:
How to store relations between news and categories? Should I create three tables (news, categories, news_categories)? Is this the best method possible?

Let's see examples:
I want to query database for latest news, so I need to:
1. query for the news using join to query for news categories
2. in the loop, query to get categories name.

So, I have 10 news (10 queries) X amount of categories = total queries. Not too much?

**Update**
Here's my example. There are three following tables.

```
-- news --  
ID  
Title

-- categories --  
ID  
Name

-- news_categories --  
ID    
NewsID  
CategoryID
```

No matter what query I use, it returns all projects and projects categories names correctly, however... projects are displayed few times, according to amount of categories. Maybe I'm too tired or something, but I really can't see any solution.

**Update 2**
Here's my query:

```
SELECT N.Title, C.Name
  FROM x_news_categories AS NC
    INNER JOIN x_news AS N
      ON N.ID = NC.NewsID
    INNER JOIN x_categories AS C
      ON C.ID = NC.CategoryID
```

and here's its result:

```
Title   Name
Test    PHP
Test2   MySQL
Test2   CSS
```

Anybody has any suggestions how to solve that issue?

Regards,
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes three tables is the correct implemenation with foreign keys between news and newscategory and category and newscategory.

You're query could be something like this to return all the News Titles for a specific category name:

```
SELECT N.Title
  FROM news_categories AS NC
    INNER JOIN news AS N
      ON N.ID = NC.NewsID
    INNER JOIN Categories AS C
      ON C.ID = NC.CategoryID
  WHERE C.Name = @Category
```

You could simplify it if you already knew the CategoryID, which you probably would from a dropdown or something, then the Join to the Category table would be unnecessary and you write something like:

```
SELECT N.Title
  FROM news_categories AS NC
    INNER JOIN news AS N
      ON N.ID = NC.NewsID
  WHERE NC.CategoryID = @CategoryID
```

To select All News items with their categories in a comma separated list you would need a User Defined Function.  Here the SQL code needed to help with the logic, but the actual implementation is up to you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCategoryList
(
    @NewsID INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CategoryList VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @CategoryList = ''

    SELECT @CategoryList = COALESCE(@CategoryList + ',','') + C.[Name]
        FROM news_categories AS NC
            INNER JOIN categories AS C
                ON NC.CategoryID = C.ID
        WHERE NC.NewsID = @NewsID

    RETURN @CategoryList
END
```

Using the above UDF your query would look like this:

```
SELECT Title, fnCategoryList(ID) AS Categories
  FROM news
```

Depending on the number of records in your news table, this query will not perform very well.  You should have some form of WHERE clause on nearly every query you write.

Comment: I suppose your answer is correct, but I'm having some problems implementing it. I edited my question, would you be so nice and take a look?

Comment: I have updated my example queries above to match your sample tables.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem you are having?  Do you have foreign keys between the tables?  Are there duplicates in the news_categories table (same newsid and same categoryid multiple times)?  If you post a query that doesn't work, I'll be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: There is no WHERE clause in your queries.  ALL rows from the news_categories table will be returned as a result and since this is a many to many implementation, there will be duplicates.  I can help you write an appropriate WHERE clause (see above for filtering based on category, but this could easily be switched to filter on news).

Comment: And this was an issue, Chris. I'd like to display all news, without any filter. There was small misunerstanding I think. So, the only way to display news categories (css, php, mysql) is to run separate queries and display then in a loop?

Comment: Yes.  You would change the WHERE to NC.NewsID = @NewsID and then execute this for each news item.  There are things you can do to return all of the categories on a single line (and then parse them).  If you give me an example of how you are expecting the data to be returned that might clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again. This is what I need. Display a list of all news, one of the column in table is Cateogires where I'd like to have comma separated categories. Something like that: 1. Test title (posted in PHP, CSS), 2. Second news (posted in HTML, CSS). Some this would be a good clarification.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a sample of how to get a table with the Title in one column and the categories in a comma separated list in the other.

Comment: Chris, need assistance again. I cannot find any error but PHPMyAdmin shoots me an error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@NewsID INT ) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS BEGIN DECLARE @CategoryList VARC' at line 3`